# How to get more than 25 records returned from my couch db using Fauxton/Selector query only (not CURL)

Tags: c#, couchdb, fauxton

When ever i try to fetch records from my couch db GetAsync method (not Find Async) i usually get only 25 records.

I am working with Angular 12, API.NET web api core and couch db. So i am writing my code is C# and looking for a specific selector in case i need to get more than 25 records from the couch DB.

currently my selector looks something like this no other query is attached to it as i need the entire door data not just top 25.

---

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to delete your question there is a 'delete' link just below the question text.

Answer (score 0):

Per CouchDB documentation:

> Refer to the [view endpoint](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/ddoc/views.html#api-ddoc-view) documentation for a complete
> description of the available query parameters and the format of the
> returned data.

Specifically, the `limit` parameter.  The default `limit` is 25.

Comment: @SivaSagarJagga opinionated for sure, but my experience tells requesting a million documents in one request is a brittle approach which invites failure. Consider a flow which requests X documents at a time, accumulating the results.